# Effect of Background Color on Battery Life in Android App

Tags: applications, battery-life

I am studying about the effect of different parameters of Android app on Power Consumption and tips for optimizing them . I came across this 
[paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix10/tech/full_papers/Carroll.pdf) which states that ligh background color consumes less power than dark bg color.
I wonder whether We can apply the same logic for apps. When I measured the power consumed by changing the back ground color of a mock Android App , I couldn't notice any change .
Is the change too small to notice or it didn't occur at all?

Comment: It would also vary with the type of screen, blacks on AMOLED screens do not turn on the cell, so there is no power drain. It's a bit more complicated than the paper suggests. Really the brightness will have far more effect than a colour, unless you are going all white or all black, and even then the screen type and the software rendering will have a huge impact.

Comment: It would be great if you can refer a paper so that I can study and include it in my thesis

Comment: where in the paper you refer to are you reading this?  it's the opposite of what I expect although it clearly depends on the display technology which has changed a good bit since that paper was written.

Answer (score -1):

It would also vary with the type of screen, blacks on AMOLED screens do not turn on the cell, so there is no power drain. It's a bit more complicated than the paper suggests. Really the brightness will have far more effect than a colour, unless you are going all white or all black, and even then the screen type and the software rendering will have a huge impact. –  RossC Oct 22 '14 at 10:52

Comment: 1) Always, kindly ask the user (RossC here) to post the comment into an answer and wait for few days (a week or so). 2) If the user does show up but doesn't post an answer or doesn't show up at all, then consider quoting his/her comment  into an answer and make the latter a wiki, so that the commenter can always edit it or shouldn't end up thinking that you tried to steal his/her reputation.